# Как получить координаты пользователя в yandex.mapkit

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Подскажите пожалуйста решение.

Как получить координаты пользователя в yandex.mapkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать Interface LocationManager.